# Trying to document 2-dimensional-related objects with doxygen

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I am working on some 2D geometry code, in particular a line-class. I have made an `enum` to describe the relation of line (let's not get into detail concerning this). However to document this, I have something like this:

```
enum enumRELATION {

   /*!this line  #######
    * other line -------
    *                   
    *     |             
    *  #######          
    *     |             
    *     |             
    */
   RELATION_INTERSECT,

   ...

};
```

If I let doxygen parse that file, to generate an HTML-file, in the HTML-file this looks like crap (of course). In other words the 2D-plane I try to show is all wrong. I know I can use `<br>`, to at least get the line breaks, but that's only half the story, because the spaces are still not correct. And the `<br>`'s makes my documentation in the actual source/header-file look awful. Is there a nice way around this? Or am I too demanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surround your documentation with the `<pre> ... </pre>` element, which should nicely keep your line breaks and indentation.

`pre` is one of the HTML tags that can be safely used in Doxygen documentations, according to this page: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/htmlcmds.html

Alternatively, you can embed images in your documentation, using the \image command: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdimage

I believe the use of proper images might make the documentation clearer to understand than using 'ascii art' ;)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. Works! I didn't know of the <pre>-HTML tag in general. This will be helpful in other contexts too. Cool.